# Send file from javascript to Python via Ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, ajax

I'm having a problem sending a file object to python through an ajax call.
I'm using [Dropzone](http://www.dropzonejs.com/) just as my "file uploader interface" and I'm sending a call when certain button is pressed.

In python when I try to process the file, it says **" 'str' object has no attribute 'seek' "**

My JS Code:

```
...
window.$form_add_file = $("#form_add_file");
var file = dropzone.files[0];
...

var formData = $form_add_file.serializeArray();

if(file){

    $modal_add_file.find($drop_add_file).removeClass("error");

    var filetype = file.type.split("/")[0].toLowerCase();
    var hasFile = checkFileType(filetype);
    if(!hasFile) { filetype = "file" }

    formData.push(
        { name: "file", value: file },
        { name: "file_type", value: filetype },
        { name: "file_name", value: file.name },
        { name: "file_size", value: file.size }
    );

} else {
    error = true;
    $modal_add_file.find($drop_add_file).addClass("error");
    return false;
}

if(!error){
    $.ajax({
        method: "POST",
        url: host + "json.references.new",
        data: formData,
        cache: false,
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(data){
            if(data){
                if(data.error){
                    modalMessage($modal_add_file, data.error, "ok");
                } else {
                    refreshData(data);
                }
            }
        },
        error: function(error){
            modalMessage($modal_add_file, oops_message, "ok");
        }
    });
}
```

My Python Code:

```
try:

    file_path = os.path.join(path, file_name)
    temp_file_path = file_path + '~'
    file.seek(0) # error happen here
    with open(temp_file_path, 'wb') as output_file:
        shutil.copyfileobj(file, output_file)
    os.rename(temp_file_path, file_path)
```

I've been searching for this on the internet and found nothing yet.

Sorry for the poor english.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

`seek` is a method for file objects, not strings.

I think your code snippet is missing some lines, but if `file` is supposed to be the file pointed to by `file_path` then you should first open the file with `file = open(file_path, 'rb')`. New file objects should start reading at the 0th position, so `file.seek(0)` should be unnecessary.